# Need regex to match 1 or more of exactly n-digit numbers

Tags: regex

I need a regex to match a series of one or more n-digit numbers, separated by comma, ie:

abc12345def returns 12345
abc12345,23456def returns 12345,23456

so far I got this: `\d{5}(,\d{5})*`

problem is it also matches in cases like these:

123456 returns 12345, but I need it not to match if the number is longer than 5. So I need numbers of exactly 5 digits, and if a number is shorter or longer it's a no-match

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Which language are you using for your regexes?  You want to put non-digit markers around your `\d{5}`'s; here is the Perl syntax (with a negative look-ahead/look-behind fix by Lukasz):

```
(?<![\d,])\d{5}(,\d{5})*(?![\d,])
```

Comment: Actually I think I got it! "(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d)(,(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d))*"   I used the look-ahead and look-behind

Comment: This works for me, capturing the 'partial matches' that mine didn't (example: `abc12345,12345,123xyz`)

Comment: @Colin O'Dell: It's not supposed to match those cases, but I'm not sure that's specified.  When you test it against your input, I assume you get `12345,12345` as the matched part, right?  It might be that comma needs to be in the lookahead and lookbehind assertions as well as digits.

Comment: @Jeremiah: Looks good to me! I definitely like your solution better than mine :P And if Lukasz also needed capturing, it can be done with a very simple addition: `(?<![\d,])(\d{5}(?:,\d{5})*)(?![\d,])` (results: http://i.imgur.com/8yrdJ.png)

Comment: I was actually testing it with the capturing, but without the `?:` in the `*` part (I was only printing `$1`).

Answer (score 3):

Actually I think I got it! `(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d)(,(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d))*`

I used the look-ahead and look-behind

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this one:

```
/\D?\d{5}(?:,\d{5})?\D?/
```

**explanation:**

```
/   : regex delimiter
\D? : non digit optionnal
\d{5}   : 5 digits
(?: : begining of non-capture group
,\d{5}  : comma and 5 digits
)?  : end of group optionnal
\D? : non digit optionnal
/   : regex delimiter
```